# Force Makefile to execute script before building targets

Tags: makefile, target

I am using Makefiles.

However, there is a command (zsh script) I want executed before any targets is executed.
How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are several techniques to have code executed before targets are built. Which one you should choose depends a little on exactly what you want to do, and why you want to do it. (What does the zsh script do? Why do you have to execute it?)

You can either do like @John suggests; placing the zsh script as the first dependency. You should then mark the `zsh` target as `.PHONY` unless it actually generates a file named `zsh`.

Another solution (in GNU make, at least) is to invoke the `$(shell ...)` function as part of a variable assignment:

```
ZSH_RESULT:=$(shell zsh myscript.zsh)
```

This will execute the script as soon as the makefile is parsed, and before **any** targets are executed. It will also execute the script if you invoke the makefile recursively.

Comment: Note, the `$(shell ...)` runs even when make is given the -n, --just-print, --dry-run, --recon option.

Comment: Nice answer. Is there any way to run a command upon exiting make? Posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20582006/force-makefile-to-execute-script-after-building-any-target-just-before-exiting

Comment: I like this approach. However, output from myscript.zsh is not printed out. I am in a similar situation where the script will prompt for a user password as `sudo` is invoked.

Comment: @Saichovsky If you just want the output to be printed, you can redirect stdout to stderr `>&2`.
Not sure if it will make `sudo` work though, as you need stdin

Answer (score 10):

Just make that a dependancy of one of the other targets

```
foo.obj : zsh foo.c 
   rule for compileing foo.c

zsh: 
   rule for running zsh script.
```

or alternatively, make your first target depend on it

```
goal: zsh foo.exe
```

Comment: The problem with the first solution here is that it will force `foo.obj` to be rebuilt every time, even if `foo.c` hasn't been updated. The problem with the second is that now you can't call your makefile with multiple targets.

Answer (score 7):

Solution for both preprocessing and postprocessing in makefiles using MAKECMDGOALS and double colon rules.

MAKECMDGOALS are the targets listed on the command line.

First step is to get the first and last targets from the command line, 
or if there are no targets listed, use the default target.

```
ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),)
FIRST_GOAL := $(word 1, $(MAKECMDGOALS))
LAST_GOAL := $(word $(words $(MAKECMDGOALS)), $(MAKECMDGOALS))
else
FIRST_GOAL := all
LAST_GOAL := all
endif
```

Double colon rules allow multiple recipes for the same target executed in order. You'll have to change all command line targets to double colon rules.

```
#Dummy rule to set the default
.PHONY: all
all ::

#Preprocessing
$(FIRST_GOAL) ::
    echo "Starting make..."

all :: normal_prerequistes
    normal_recipe

other_stuff

#Postprocessing
$(LAST_GOAL) ::
    echo "All done..."
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a solution without modifying your existing `Makefile` (main difference with the accepted answer). Just create a `makefile` containing:

```
.PHONY: all

all:
    pre-script
    @$(MAKE) -f Makefile --no-print-directory $(MAKECMDGOALS) MAKE='$(MAKE) -f Makefile'
    post-script

$(MAKECMDGOALS): all ;
```

The only drawback is that the pre- and post- scripts will always be run, even if there is nothing else to do. But they will not be run if you invoke make with one of the `--dry-run` options (other difference with the accepted answer).

Comment: I added the `.PHONY: all` and `all: version` in which "version" prints lib version.It does not get executed on other targets such as `help`