# Makefile: creating a file before building any target

Tags: makefile

( my question is different from [Force Makefile to execute script before building targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122602) )

I've got the following **Makefile**:

```
.PHONY: dump_params all

all: tmpA

tmpA: tmpB tmpC dump_params
    cat $(filter tmp%,$^) > $@

tmpB: dump_params
    touch $@

tmpC: dump_params
    touch $@

dump_params:
    echo "Makefile was run." >> config.txt
```

with the target dump_params I want to create/append a file each time a new target is invoked (to keep track of the version of the tools used). However, when I call

```
make tmpA
```

all the targets are built from scratch

```
$ make tmpA
echo "Makefile was run " >> config.txt
touch tmpB
touch tmpC
cat tmpB tmpC > tmpA

$ make tmpA
echo "Makefile was run." >> config.txt
touch tmpB
touch tmpC
cat tmpB tmpC > tmpA
```

How can I prevent Make to re-build everything because of that target 'dump_params'? Is there a another way to create this kind of log file ?

**EDIT**: I'm using a parallel make (option -j). Defining a macro to create the file in the statements section is not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [order-only prerequisites](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types)?

```
.PHONY: dump_params all

all: tmpA

tmpA: tmpB tmpC | dump_params
    cat $(filter tmp%,$^) > $@

tmpB: | dump_params
    touch $@

tmpC: | dump_params
    touch $@

dump_params:
    echo "Makefile was run." >> config.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use immediately expanded shell functions, like:

```
__dummy := $(shell echo "Makefile was run." >> config.txt)
```

Since it's immediately expanded the shell script will be invoked once, as the makefile is read in.  There's no need to define a `dump_params` target or include it as a prerequisite.  This is more old-school, but has the advantage that it will run for *every* invocation of make, without having to go through and ensure every target has the proper order-only prerequisite defined.

Comment: very nice solution too !

Comment: even though "( my question is different from Force Makefile to execute script before building targets )", it turns out that this also solves this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Non-answer, but snakemake (and there are others, I suspect) supports tracking of rules (the code), parameters, inputs, and executable versions.

https://bitbucket.org/johanneskoester/snakemake

Comment: Thank you Sean, but I'd like to stick to qmake + SGE (  http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qmake.html )